# What is a vtier?

Tags: placeholder

In the IT industry, I've heard people mention "vtiers" in relation to the production hardware. What is a vtier?

Comment: vtier or vsphere?

Comment: vtier [Extra characters so i can post the comment, please fix this stack exchange...]

Comment: The limit is a feature, not a bug. (You could have posted "`@peelman: vtier`" to get around it; see the help text.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vtier as I am used to it is simply "virtual tier".  Or, in other words, a virtualized layer / level of operation.